# I have got ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception..What is the reason?I diid'nt understand

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

This is the java code

```
String arr[]=new String[3];
String opdate=null; 
list=new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(); 
while(rs.next())
{   
    opdate=rs.getString(1);
    arr=opdate.split("-");
    if(arr[1]==month)
    {
        list.add(rs.getString(1));
        list.add(rs.getString(2));
        list.add(rs.getString(3));
        list.add(rs.getString(4));
        list.add(rs.getString(5));
        list.add(rs.getString(6));
        list.add(rs.getString(7));
    }
}
```

this returns nothing..where am i wrong?? plz help me out

Comment: Where is the query to execute?

Comment: first check in what format date is comming?? alert(rs.getString(1))

Comment: date comes in yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: I have got ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception